# How would i go about editing the element within the div?

Tags: javascript

How would i go about editing the style within this div
- `style="width: 723px;"`
full div code
`<div class="icon-column" style="width: 723px;"></div>`

i would prefer javascript with a var so the change doesn't automatically go to the old width when zooming in or out.

```
var elementList = document.querySelectorAll(".icon-column");

Array.prototype.forEach.call( elementList, function( node ) {
   node.parentNode.removeChild( node );
});
```

but instead of removing it i would like to edit the style element.

Answer (score 0):

```
node.style.width = '500px';
```

Or, if you plan on using a variable:

```
node.style.width = nameOfVar + 'px';
```